# Various table settings and options

Tags: tables, luatex, enumitem, arabic, easylist

For the shown MWE, I managed to put the data in tabular form in conjunction with using [itemized] list, however, I have the following issues:

- I need to use the [easylist] package instead of the [itemize] package but this does not seem to work.
- For the merged rows in the last column, I have the issue which is that: despite of  being able to insert an itemized list, yet it seems to ignore unequal distribution of dimensons between rows, so it expanded the second row while leaving the first row with the same height, I need the extra space to be distributed evenly between rows.
- Also when using multirow: Although I am merging 2 rows, yet I merged 6 rows to get the text position properly, although I only have 3 rows within the table, so it should have given me an error.
- Finally, how can I remove the vertical line on the upepr right corner (The upper most cell in the first column is empty, I managed to remove the upper line, but the vertical line I failed to remove it)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Simplified Arabic}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{9}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,5]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,6]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,7]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,8]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,9]{label=$\bullet$}
\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{9}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt} 

\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu,multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}




\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 


\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{center}
\caption{التفخيم والترقيقXIV باللغة العربية}
\label{tab:التفخيم والترقيق}
\begin{tabular}{?{1mm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}?{1mm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}?{1mm}} 
\rowcolor{white}
\cmidrule[2.5pt]{2-5}
\rowcolor{white} 


 &
\textbf{التعريف}
 &
\textbf{الحروف}
 & 
\textbf{أمثلة}
 & 
\textbf{ملاحظات}  
\\
\rowcolor{gray!25}  
\midrule[2.5pt]
\textbf{التفخيم}
 &
تسمين صوت الحرف عند النطق به
 &
"خُـصّ ضَـغْـطٍ قِـظْ" (تسمى حروف الاستعلاء)
 & 
 خــالـديـن
الــصـادقـين
الــضـالـين
 &  
\cellcolor{white}
\\
  \cmidrule[2pt]{1-4} 
\textbf{الترقيق}
 &
تنحيف صوت الحرف عند النطق به
 &
بـاقي أحرف اللغة العربية (تسمى حروف الاستفال)
 & 
الــتــائـبون
الــعابدون
الــحامدون
 &  
\cellcolor{white}\multirow{-6}{*}
{\parbox{5cm}
{
\textbf{وهنالك أحرف الأصل فيها الترقيق ولكنها تفخم في الحالات التالية:}
}}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm]
\item
الألف المدية :
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm]
\item
 تتبع ما قبلها تفخيما وترقيقا.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm]
\item
حرف اللام في لفظ الجلالة(الله):
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm]
\item
إذا سبق لفظ الجلالة فتح أو ضم
\item
عند البدء ب لفظ الجلالة.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm]
\item
 حرف الراء:
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm]
\item
عندما يكون مفتوحا أو مضموما.
\item
عندما يكون ساكنا III وقبله فتح أو ضم.
\item
 عندما يأتي ساكنا III بعد كسر وبعده في الكلمة نفسها حرف تفخيم.
\item
عندما يقع بعد كسر عارض.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\\
\bottomrule[1mm] 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output + Descroption]

Comment: Off-topic: the `geometry` option set `top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm` may be simplified to `margin=2.5cm`. In addition, since `a4paper` is given as a document class option, it needn't be repeated as a `geometry` option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the `easylist` package. I trust, though, that the following solution -- which relies on the capabilities of the `enumitem` package -- meets your requirements.

Note that I've simplified both the structure of the preamble and the nested-list structure in the left-hand column considerably. I've also switched to a `tabularx` environment, which (I believe) simplifies many column-width calculations and automatically assures that the table will fit inside the text block. Finally, it's no longer necessary to load the `multirow` package.

If you wish to change the symbol for second-level items from `\textbullet` to `\textendash`, simply change the instruction `\setlist[itemize,2]{label={\small\textbullet}, leftmargin=3mm, nosep}` to `\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\textendash, leftmargin=3mm, nosep}`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Simplified Arabic} 
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textbullet, left=0pt, nosep,
    before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\raggedright}, 
    after ={\end{minipage}}}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label={\small\textbullet}, leftmargin=3mm, nosep}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}} % vertical centering
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

%% Load the 'hyperref' package last:
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt} % default is '0.4pt'
\caption{التفخيم والترقيقXIV باللغة العربية}
\label{tab:التفخيم والترقيق}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%
   ?{1mm}
   M{1cm}
   ?{1mm}
   M{2.5cm}|  
   M{2cm}|
   M{2cm}|
   L
   ?{1mm}} 
\cmidrule[2.5pt]{2-5}
%% first header row:
\multicolumn{1}{r@{\vrule width 1mm}}{} % empty first cell
 & \textbf{التعريف}
 & \textbf{الحروف}
 & \textbf{أمثلة}
 & \hfil\textbf{ملاحظات}\hfill
\\
\midrule[2.5pt]
%% second header row:
\rowcolor{gray!25}  
\textbf{التفخيم}
 &
تسمين صوت الحرف عند النطق به
 &
"خُـصّ ضَـغْـطٍ قِـظْ" (تسمى حروف الاستعلاء)
 & 
 خــالـديـن
الــصـادقـين
الــضـالـين
 &  
\cellcolor{white} 
\textbf{وهنالك أحرف الأصل فيها الترقيق ولكنها تفخم في الحالات التالية:}
\\
\cmidrule[2pt]{1-4} 
%% body of table:
\textbf{الترقيق}
 &
تنحيف صوت الحرف عند النطق به
 &
بـاقي أحرف اللغة العربية (تسمى حروف الاستفال)
 & 
الــتــائـبون
الــعابدون
الــحامدون
 &  
\begin{itemize} % start level 1
\item 
الألف المدية :
\begin{itemize} % start level 2
\item
 تتبع ما قبلها تفخيما وترقيقا.
\end{itemize} % end level 2
\item
حرف اللام في لفظ الجلالة(الله):
\begin{itemize} % start level 2
\item
إذا سبق لفظ الجلالة فتح أو ضم
\item
عند البدء ب لفظ الجلالة.
\end{itemize} % end level 2
\item 
 حرف الراء:
\begin{itemize} % start level 2
\item 
عندما يكون مفتوحا أو مضموما.
\item
عندما يكون ساكنا III وقبله فتح أو ضم.
\item
 عندما يأتي ساكنا III بعد كسر وبعده في الكلمة نفسها حرف تفخيم.
\item
عندما يقع بعد كسر عارض.
\end{itemize} % end level 2
\end{itemize} % end level 1
\\
\bottomrule[1mm] 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

**Addendum**: I can't help but remark that the broken vertical lines in the table aren't all that attractive and that both the vertical and horizontal lines seem excessively and unnecessarily thick and heavy. The following variant solution addresses these solutions by setting the widths of all rules to `1pt` (the system default is `0.4pt`), by using `\hline` and `\cline` instead of `\midrule`, `\cmidrule`, and `\bottomrule`, and by setting the value of the length parameter `\extrarowheight` to `4pt`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{booktabs}  % no longer needed

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Simplified Arabic} 
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textbullet, left=0pt, nosep,
    before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\raggedright}, 
    after ={\end{minipage}}}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label={\small\textbullet}, leftmargin=3mm, nosep}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

%% load 'hyperref' last:
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}
\caption{التفخيم والترقيقXIV باللغة العربية}
\label{tab:التفخيم والترقيق}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%
   |
   M{1cm}
   |
   M{2.5cm}|  
   M{2cm}|
   M{2cm}|
   L
   |} 
\cline{2-5}
%% first header row
   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} % empty first cell
 & \textbf{التعريف}
 & \textbf{الحروف}
 & \textbf{أمثلة}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{ملاحظات}}
\\
\hline
%% second header row
\rowcolor{gray!20}  
\textbf{التفخيم}
 &
تسمين صوت الحرف عند النطق به
 &
"خُـصّ ضَـغْـطٍ قِـظْ" (تسمى حروف الاستعلاء)
 & 
 خــالـديـن
الــصـادقـين
الــضـالـين
 &  
\cellcolor{white} 
\textbf{وهنالك أحرف الأصل فيها الترقيق ولكنها تفخم في الحالات التالية:}
\\
\cline{1-4} 
%% body of table
\textbf{الترقيق}
 &
تنحيف صوت الحرف عند النطق به
 &
بـاقي أحرف اللغة العربية (تسمى حروف الاستفال)
 & 
الــتــائـبون
الــعابدون
الــحامدون
 &  
\begin{itemize} % start level 1
\item 
الألف المدية :
\begin{itemize} % start level 2
\item
 تتبع ما قبلها تفخيما وترقيقا.
\end{itemize} % end level 2
\item
حرف اللام في لفظ الجلالة(الله):
\begin{itemize} % start level 2
\item
إذا سبق لفظ الجلالة فتح أو ضم
\item
عند البدء ب لفظ الجلالة.
\end{itemize} % end level 2
\item 
 حرف الراء:
\begin{itemize} % start level 2
\item 
عندما يكون مفتوحا أو مضموما.
\item
عندما يكون ساكنا III وقبله فتح أو ضم.
\item
 عندما يأتي ساكنا III بعد كسر وبعده في الكلمة نفسها حرف تفخيم.
\item
عندما يقع بعد كسر عارض.
\end{itemize} % end level 2
\end{itemize} % end level 1
\\
\hline %% \bottomrule[1mm] 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

- First, regarding unequal row heights: the use of mini-page or parbox is avoided where the `multirow` package with its options is used so as to better merge the rows.
- Second, extra row height is obtained through the use of the command `\rule{0cm}{5.5cm}` for the rows which you want to increase its height.
- Third, proper vertical alignment for the first column is obtained through the adding an extra empty column `@{}m{0cm}@{}` as described in [Vertical alignment in table: m-column, row size - problem in last column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68732/vertical-alignment-in-table-m-column-row-size-problem-in-last-column)
- Fourth, regarding the removal of vertical lines in certain portions of the table: the answer given [Remove vertical lines for table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36798/remove-vertical-lines-for-table) shows how to control vertical lines in tables using the `multicolumn` option in order to override the column defined at the beginning of the table.
- Finally, regarding the use of `Easy-list`, this requires further trials in order to resolve it. The package manual mentioned something about using `\activate` and `\deactivate`, however, it is a bit hard to achieve a solution.

Here is the modified solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 


\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Simplified Arabic}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{9}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,5]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,6]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,7]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,8]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,9]{label=$\bullet$}
\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{9}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt} 

\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\ListProperties(
                Style1*=\textbullet\ \ ,
                Style2*=\begin{normalfont}\begin{bfseries}\textendash\end{bfseries}\end{normalfont} \ \ ,
                Style3*=\textasteriskcentered\ \ ,
                Style4*=\textperiodcentered\ \ ,
                Style5*=\textbullet\ \ ,
                Style6*=\begin{normalfont}\begin{bfseries}\textendash\end{bfseries}\end{normalfont}\ \ ,
                Style7*=\textasteriskcentered\ \ ,
                Style8*=\textperiodcentered\ \ ,
                Hide1=1,
                Hide2=2,
                Hide3=3,
                Hide4=4,
                Hide5=5,
                Hide6=6,
                Hide7=7,
                Hide8=8 )
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu,multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}[2]{!{\vrule width #1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}




\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 


\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{center}
\caption{التفخيم والترقيقXIV باللغة العربية}
\label{tab:التفخيم والترقيق}
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{0cm}@{}?{1mm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}c?{1mm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{6.5cm}?{1mm}}
\rowcolor{white}
\cmidrule[2.5pt]{3-6}
\rowcolor{white} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
\cellcolor{white}
 &

 &
\textbf{التعريف}
 &
\textbf{الحروف}
 & 
\textbf{أمثلة}
 & 
\textbf{ملاحظات}  
\\
\cmidrule[2pt]{2-6}
\rowcolor{gray!25}   
\rule{0cm}{5.5cm} 
\cellcolor{white}
 &
\textbf{التفخيم}
 &
تسمين صوت الحرف عند النطق به
 &
"خُـصّ ضَـغْـطٍ قِـظْ" (تسمى حروف الاستعلاء)
 & 
 خــالـديـن
الــصـادقـين
الــضـالـين
 &  
\cellcolor{white}
\multirow[c]{2}{=}[2.5cm]
{
\textbf{وهنالك أحرف الأصل فيها الترقيق ولكنها تفخم في الحالات التالية:}
\begin{itemize}
\item
الألف المدية :
\begin{itemize}
\item
 تتبع ما قبلها تفخيما وترقيقا.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item
حرف اللام في لفظ الجلالة(الله):
\begin{itemize}
\item
إذا سبق لفظ الجلالة فتح أو ضم
\item
عند البدء ب لفظ الجلالة.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item
حرف الراء:
\begin{itemize}
\item
عندما يكون مفتوحا أو مضموما.
\item
عندما يكون ساكنا III وقبله فتح أو ضم.
\item
عندما يأتي ساكنا III بعد كسر وبعده في الكلمة نفسها حرف تفخيم.
\item
عندما يقع بعد كسر عارض.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}
\\
  \cmidrule[2pt]{2-5} 
  \rule{0cm}{5.5cm}
  \cellcolor{white}
 &
    \textbf{الترقيق}
 &
تنحيف صوت الحرف عند النطق به
 &
بـاقي أحرف اللغة العربية (تسمى حروف الاستفال)
 & 
الــتــائـبون
الــعابدون
الــحامدون
 &  

\\
\cmidrule[2pt]{2-6}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```