# Text alignment and row height in latex table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, itemize

Regarding the shown MWE (Compiled with Lualatex, I needed to add bulleted text in the table and for such reason I encountered 2 issues:

- First, Regarding table position: I used the mini-page environment so as to add bulleted text in merged rows, however, upon modifying the mini-page region through the "Vspace" command, the table as a whole is shifted to become in the center of the page and the remaining text below it is mitigated to the next page.
- Second, regarding bulleted items, item indentation is the same, and is not different at different bullet levels, also I tried to used "easy list" but it did not work, I wonder if this is possible.
- Third, Regarding text position in rows: I have been trying to modify row height for certain rows in the latex table such that the text in such rows remian centered vertically and horizontally, the reason for increasing row heights is to compensate for the merged text shown in the merged rows. For such reason I used the solutoion proposed by "Steven B. Segletes" [How to specify the row height in LaTeX table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19589/how-to-specify-the-row-height-in-latex-table)
  Where he added such lines to the preamble So as to use the command "\xrowht[]{}" to modify row height

```
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}
```

However, upon doing so, the text vertical alignment is shifted in a random matter

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabu,multirow} 
\usepackage{array} 
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowbottomsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{boldline} 

\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}

\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\setlength{\parskip}{1em} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6} 


\makeatletter 
\def\toclevel@subsubparagraph{6}
\providecommand\theHsubsubparagraph {\theHsubparagraph.\arabic{subsubparagraph}}
\newcounter {subsubparagraph}[subparagraph]
\renewcommand\thesubsubparagraph {\thesubparagraph.\@arabic\c@subsubparagraph}
\newcommand*\l@subsubparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{12em}{6em}}
\newcommand\subsubparagraph{\@startsection{subsubparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
\makeatother



\setcounter{tocdepth}{6} 
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec} 
    \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
    \titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
    \titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
    \titlespacing{\subsubsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
    \titlespacing{\subsubsubsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
    \titlespacing{\subsubsubsubsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}


\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ulem}


\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{9}

\setlistdepth{9}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt} 

\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\textendash}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=*}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label=·}
\setlist[itemize,5]{label =}
\setlist[itemize,6]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,7]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,8]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,9]{label=$\bullet$}



\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 



\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt} 
\begin{center}
\caption{التفخيم والترقيقXIV باللغة العربية}
\label{tab:التفخيم والترقيق}
\begin{tabular}{?{1mm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}?{1mm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}?{1mm}} 
\rowcolor{white} 
\cmidrule[2.5pt]{2-5}
\rowcolor{white} 


 &
\textbf{التعريف}
 &
\textbf{الحروف}
 & 
\textbf{أمثلة}
 & 
\textbf{ملاحظات}  
\\

\rowcolor{gray!25}  
\midrule[2.5pt]
\xrowht{150pt}
\textbf{التفخيم}
 &
تسمين صوت الحرف عند النطق به
 &
"خُـصّ ضَـغْـطٍ قِـظْ" (تسمى حروف الاستعلاء)
 & 
 خــالـديـن
الــصـادقـين
الــضـالـين
 &  
\cellcolor{white}

\\
  \cmidrule[2pt]{1-4} 
  \xrowht{150pt} 
\textbf{الترقيق}
 &
تنحيف صوت الحرف عند النطق به
 &
بـاقي أحرف اللغة العربية (تسمى حروف الاستفال)
 & 
الــتــائـبون
الــعابدون
الــحامدون
 &  

\multirow{-2}{*}
{
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
{
\vspace{-6.5cm}
\textbf{وهنالك أحرف الأصل فيها الترقيق ولكنها تفخم في الحالات التالية:}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm]
\item
الألف المدية :
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm]
\item
 تتبع ما قبلها تفخيما وترقيقا.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm]
\item
حرف اللام في لفظ الجلالة(الله):
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm]
\item
إذا سبق لفظ الجلالة فتح أو ضم
\item
عند البدء ب لفظ الجلالة.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm]
\item
حرف الراء:
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.3cm]
\item
عندما يكون مفتوحا أو مضموما.
\item
عندما يكون ساكنا III وقبله فتح أو ضم.
\item
عندما يأتي ساكنا III بعد كسر وبعده في الكلمة نفسها حرف تفخيم.
\item
عندما يقع بعد كسر عارض.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{minipage}
}
\\
\bottomrule[1mm] 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\subsection{الصوائت والصوامت}
\begin{center}
\textbf{
jhkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
jhkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Regarding vertical alignment and bulleted items, you can refer to the answer shonw in [Various table settings and options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520465/various-table-settings-and-options/528382#528382)
- Regarding table position as well as the text below, such aspect are mainly related to various text settings (line spacing, paragraph.....) set in the document.